# NavigationLinkで画面遷移したいとき

Tags: swift, xcode

NavigationLinkで遷移したいときに以下のようなコードにすると、エラーが出てしまいます。なぜでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '() -> Label'
```

**現状のコード:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let fruits = ["りんご", "オレンジ", "バナナ"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("大根")
                Text("キャベツ")
                Text("じゃがいも")
            } header: {
                Text("やさい")
            }
            Section {
                ForEach(0 ..< fruits.count) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView, label: {Text(fruits[index])})
                }
            } header: {
                Text("くだもの")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("テキスト")
```

Comment: Xcode 12.4を使って、新規プロジェクトを作り、提示いただいたコードを、そのまま記述したところ、おっしゃるエラーメッセージではなく、`Type 'AnotherView.Type' Cannot conform to 'View'`というエラーメッセージになりました。つまりこれは、実際にエラーが出たコードと、ここに提示なさったコードが、同一でないということを示しています。なので、きっちりおっしゃるエラーメッセージの出るコードに、質問文の編集を行なって、書き直してください。そうでなければ、何人も、ご質問に対して、有効な回答をすることは不可能です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`destination：AnothierView`の部分を`destination： { AnotherView() }` にすることでうまくいかないですか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。エラーは出ないのですが遷移しません。

Comment: NavigationLinkはNavigationView(NavigationStack, NavigationSplitView)の中でないと動作しません。

ListをNavigationStackで囲むことで動くようになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。